# Anonymous Code Block with DDL works but when created as procedure, get permissions error

Tags: oracle, plsql

In our Oracle 12c database, I am trying to create a package that will drop and create tables as needed.

For my first test, I wrote an anonymous code block and it works fine:

```
begin
    begin
        execute immediate 'Drop Table my_table';
        exception
           when OTHERS then
                if sqlcode = -942 then
                    null;
                end if;
    end;
    begin
        execute immediate 'Create Table my_table as
        WITH 
        sub_qy AS(
        SELECT DISTINCT
            ...
        )
        SELECT * FROM sub_qy';
    end;
    execute immediate 'GRANT SELECT ON my_table to my_role';
```

I then tried to create a package and put the anonymous code block in a procedure but when executing the procedure I get the error:

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Here is the logic:

```
create package my_refresh_pkg as
    procedure create_first_table;
end my_refresh_pkg;

create package body my_refresh_pkg as
    procedure create_first_table is
    begin
        begin
            execute immediate 'Drop Table my_table';
            exception
               when OTHERS then
                    if sqlcode = -942 then
                        null;
                    end if;
        end;
        begin
            execute immediate 'Create Table my_table as
            WITH 
            sub_qy AS(
            SELECT DISTINCT
                ...
            )
            SELECT * FROM sub_qy';
        end;
        execute immediate 'GRANT SELECT ON my_table to my_role';
    end create_first_table;
end my_refresh_pkg;
```

I created the package in my own schema, so I am not sure why I am getting this error.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: In Oracle it is a poor design to drop and re-create tables on-the-fly in PL/SQL package. According to the code a MATERIALIZED VIEW should be the perfect solution.

Comment: The `if sqlcode = -942 then` in exception handler is useless. It is `NULL;` in any case, not matter if you have `ORA-00942` or not.

Comment: Hi @WernfriedDomscheit, I have a MV Refresh group created but it does not update the MVs consistently so we have been tasked with doing it this way.  THank you, though.

Comment: You should always include the *full* error message, including the line numbers.  That line number will tell us if the error is with the `drop table`, `create table`, `grant select`, or something else.  Also, try adding `authid current_user` after the package name, it will let Oracle use role-based privileges during execution.

Answer (score 0):

Suspicious part is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       ...
```

as it *smells* like a know issue with privileges. If table(s) you used in the above statement's `FROM` clause don't belong to you but someone else, and you acquired `select` (or any other) privileges via **role**, well - it won't work in named PL/SQL procedures. Yes, that's a stored procedure, or a function, or - a `package` you wrote.

Solution is to grant those privileges directly to you, not via role.

---

**[EDIT: running your code in my database - no errors]**

```
SQL> create or replace package my_refresh_pkg as
  2      procedure create_first_table;
  3  end my_refresh_pkg;
  4  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body my_refresh_pkg as
  2      procedure create_first_table is
  3      begin
  4          begin
  5              execute immediate 'Drop Table my_table';
  6              exception
  7                 when OTHERS then
  8                      if sqlcode = -942 then
  9                          null;
 10                      end if;
 11          end;
 12          begin
 13              execute immediate 'Create Table my_table as
 14              WITH
 15              sub_qy AS(
 16              SELECT DISTINCT
 17                  job from emp
 18              )
 19              SELECT * FROM sub_qy';
 20          end;
 21          execute immediate 'GRANT SELECT ON my_table to my_role';
 22      end create_first_table;
 23  end my_refresh_pkg;
 24  /

Package body created.

SQL> create role my_role;

Role created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec my_refresh_pkg.create_first_table;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From my_table;

JOB
---------
CLERK
SALESMAN
PRESIDENT
MANAGER
ANALYST

SQL>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the suggestion. I have had that issue before (specifically with these tables that previously were materialized views); however, I have just checked and validated that my account has direct select privs on each table required.  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure what does it mean, after all - do you still have problems, or did you manage to solve them?

Comment: Hi, yes I am still having the same problem.  I did have direct select privs on the objects (granted to user, not role) but the issue still persists.  It is very odd.

Comment: Debug the procedure; find out which statement exactly raises the error. I ran your code, it executed without errors.